# Generated mailing forms not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Here's the thing. I'm developing a small web project with forms which send information through e-mail. No database storing required, just for contacting. For that purpose, I used this tool:

https://jqueryform.com/

..To generate them. They work on their own, have their own logic, using smtp and a phpmailer function. Up until now, I thought they only required to be hosted somewhere and of course, have access to internet. I tested them here (as well as in another hosting environment):

https://www.000webhost.com/

**They actually work**, generated forms do send the expected emails. I did this before I realized those forms had to work with Wordpress (it's my first time touching Wordpress). Hoping I didn't have to start again, I stored the whole generated forms packs using a file manager plugin for Wordpress. Then, created new pages and called them with iframe. Pages show forms and work as expected, they just don't send the mails.

I've made multiple testing in order to address the origin of the problems. **Files are exactly the same** in Wordpress and in "000webhost", so it's not a coding issue. If iframe is pointing to the ones hosted in "000webhost" from Wordpress, they work, so it's not iframe. They do not work only when pointing the ones hosted within the same Wordpress. I tested them in and outside wp-content and online.

I'd like someone to explain me what is likely the issue here.

Comment: Is there any error returned from wordpress? Can you check the logs?

Comment: I enabled debug, tested again yet no log file.

Comment: While this might be wordpress issue, this is hard to reproduce since you didn't provide any reproducible codes

Comment: The codes are generated using the "jqueryform" tool linked in the post, smtp configured for mailing. Didn't touch any of the code generated, just moved the packs from one hosting to another.

Comment: wait, is the Wordpress you mean is... the hosting provided by wordpress.com? Not your own?

Comment: Yes. Webpage I'm working on is hosted elsewhere. I'm using the web version of Wordpress to work.

Comment: I think wordpress.com have some limitations what you can do, anyway try to install wordpress on your 000webhost and see if this still happen

Answer (score 0):

I got to know the root of the problem. It was not Wordpress itself, but a problem of the hosting provider. GoDaddy blocks the ports of any other smtp services that are not the one their offer (like O365). In order to send mails from there, had to either use one of their mailing accounts, or call the forms from an external hosting that do allow it.